# Maintain divs visibility when hovering if div is not a child element of triggering element

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I have a simple hover over script:

```
$('#loginbutton').hover(
  function () {
    $('#loginform').stop().fadeIn('fast');
  },
  function () {
    $('#loginform').stop().fadeOut('fast');
  }
);
```

Unfortunately, `#loginform` is not a child of `#loginbutton`, though both divs overlap.

Is there a way I can maintain `#loginform`s  visibility if the mouse leaves `#loginbutton` and moves over `#loginform`?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P4sxH/

Comment: Please add the HTML, too. Or create a JSFIDDLE.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky but I think I got it:

http://jsfiddle.net/P4sxH/2/

```
$('#loginform').hover(
  function () {
    $('#loginform').stop().fadeIn('fast');
  },
  function () {
    $('#loginform').stop().fadeOut('fast');
  }
);

$('#loginbutton').hover(
  function () {
    $('#loginform').stop().fadeIn('fast');
  },
  function () {
    $('#loginform').stop().fadeOut('fast');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a timer

```
$('#loginbutton').hover(
    function () {
        $('#loginform').stop().fadeIn('fast');
    },
    function () {
        var timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $('#loginform').stop().fadeOut('fast');
        }, 200);
        $('#loginform').data('hidetimer', timer)
    }
);

$('#loginform').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout($(this).data('hidetimer'));
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeOut('fast');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v8NFc/)